# How can I create filters on a series of tables where the final table yields a single data observation?

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating an interactive 'calculator' using tableau. I have a series of dataframes that I have crossed with one another, such that the resulting dataframe is every possible combination between the tables, and every row is unique.

Each column is its own worksheet as a table. Each table in the dashboard is a pane. So, here we have a series of tables with selectable units of measurement, and the final pane on the dashboard should filter to the cell for its respective column, on the unique row of the dataset that the user has selected and 'filtered out'.

I'm having some issues getting this to work and not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can think to solving this would be 'Cascading Filters.' Here are a couple resources:

- [General Use](https://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2013/08/12/cascading-quick-filters-in-tableau-2/)
- [In dashboard action-filter form](https://interworks.com/blog/dwyers/2015/07/09/tableau-performance-checklist-filtering-use-dashboard-filter-actions/)

The critical piece, however, is that the filters must be selected in a specific order - therefore making them 'cascading.' This may differ from your presumed concept of clicking/filtering in any order on the worksheets to then arrive to a final answer. I do think that this may be a limitation of Tableau - I don't think that a 'many to many' type of relationship can be set up within Action Filters.

Comment: This led me to the correct answer eventually, but in the current version of Tableau, they are called "Hierarchical Filters". This video helped me: https://youtu.be/v_YUhryO4jY